# Сообщение во время попытки правки удаленного вопроса

Tags: дефект

Если удалить свой вопрос, а затем, без перезагрузки страницы попытаться править этот же вопрос, то всплывает сообщение:

> Не удалось загрузить сообщение

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Однако, если страницу перезагрузить, а затем попытаться править сообщение, то сообщение уже будет загружено и будет содержать следующий текст:

> Невозможно редактировать удаленный вами же вопрос. Восстановите его,
>   прежде чем приступать к редактированию.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Также отсутствует надпись сразу же после удаления вопроса:

> Удалён участником...

Надпись появляется после перезагрузки страницы.

**Это не баг, это фича?**

Comment: Это баг, но фиксить его не будут, ибо лень и затрагивает 0.005% участников :) Кстати, я кажется редактировал удалённый вопрос и без восстановления, но это может от 10к такое даётся.

Comment: @alexolut, ты путаешь вопрос и ответ. Удалённый вопрос может редактировать только модератор.

Comment: @Qwertiy может я был модератором.