# Почему Дух ставит тревогу за единственный удалённый вопрос?

Tags: поддержка, тревоги, дух-сообщества, удаление-вопросов

Пользователь удалил [1 вопрос](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/6637/178988) из 14 заданных - почему сработала автоматическая тревога?

[image: скриншот]

Comment: Вот нафига тут время регистрации участника выводить не понятно, почему бы не ограничиться датой?

Answer (score 3):

За «вандализм» принимается в том числе и удаление полезных вопросов. На момент удаления у вопроса было +3 голоса. Это вполне могло сработатать за проверку. Также стоит обратить внимание на [временную шкалу вопроса](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/6637/timeline): автор в общей сложности удалил вопрос 5 раз с 4 восстановлениями. Судя по всему для подготовки баг репорта: [Сообщение во время попытки правки удаленного вопроса](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/6638/176217)

Нашел [пост](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/203062/339911) на MSE. Речь про множественные удаления за короткий промежуток времени. Похоже тут действительно имеет место баг, не учитывающий идентификатор удаляемого сообщения. Другими словами: нужен map, а не multimap для хранения id.

Comment: Интересно, а может это баг и Дух не учёл, что 4 удалениями удалён всего один вопрос?))

Comment: @Qwertiy может и так, но я склоняюсь к версии удаления "полезного" сообщения.

Comment: Странно, учитывая что за это дается знак "Дисциплинированный". Дисциплина наказуема?

Comment: @MSDN.WhiteKnight в первую очередь [знак за удаление ответа](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/7609/339911). Я даже не думал, что и за вопрос его могут дать.